# Is it correct to say that a particle in the box can only acquire discrete velocities?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, velocity, discrete

My thermodynamics lecture script says the following:

## Translational Energy Levels

### In addition to electronic energy, atoms have translational energy.

To find allowed translational energies we solve Ψ for a particle of mass *m* in a box of variable side lenghts.

In 1D, motion is along the *x* demension and the particle is constrained to the interval 0 ≤ x ≤ a.

Allowed energy states are given by: $$\epsilon_n = \frac{n^2h^2}{8ma^2}, n = 1,2,3,..$$

So the allowed energy states are only dependent on mass *m* and box length *a*.

I wondered if depending on the speed of the particle moving back and forth in this 1D box (for example when increasing the temperature, thus increasing the velocity) the increasing translational energy (or kinetic energy) is always exactly equal to some $\epsilon_n$ with the right integer for *n*?

*Or with an analogy, in this box, I can only throw a baseball at discrete velocities, specifically only those velocities that generate translational energy matching whole numbers n according to the above formula and the heavier my baseball, and even more significantly, the longer the field, the smaller the jumps between states and the ball can acquire more and more "continuous" velocities*?

For example, would that be right?

Assuming I have a hydrogen atom in the box described above with $a = 1 nm$, the lowest possible velocity ($n = 1$) is then:

$$\epsilon_1 = \frac{h^2}{8*m(H)*1E-8} = 3,278E-25 J$$
$$E_t = \frac{1}{2}mv^2 <=> v = \sqrt{\frac{2E}{m}} = 19,79 m/s$$

The next possible velocity ($n = 2$) would equal 39,58 m/s and so on...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What do you mean "velocity"? Do you mean the expectation value? Quantum particles generally have a probability distribution for both position and velocity, and in this case your energy eigenstates with the energies given by your formula are not velocity eigenstates.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer Maybe I'm thinking too classically, I'm currently in an introductory course on thermodynamics and at the very beginning they talk about how energy is stored in the first place, among other things they explain that it can be stored as translation energy and then they show the model with the 1d box and explain that only these energy states can be assumed with these boundary conditions. 1/2

Comment: Then the question arose in my mind whether at each speed of the particle the energy then corresponds to an n in this formula. The wave nature was not introduced, but it was said that the particle in the 1d box can move from left to right. 2/2

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer I have a slide telling me: How is energy stored in a molecule?
Electronic energy: changes in the kinetic and potential energy of one or more electrons associated with the molecule. Same as many-electron atoms.
**Translational energy**. The molecule can move (translate) in space. Same particle-in-a-box solutions as for atoms.
Rotational... Vibrational...

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/197515/25301

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Measuring the momentum (or velocity) of a particle in an infinite square well is a tricky issue, with some apparent contradictions, most of them sorted out in this paper; "[The Particle in a Box is not Simple](https://pubs.aip.org/aapt/ajp/article/45/2/158/1050612/The-particle-in-a-box-is-not-simple?searchresult=1)".

The paper starts out with your observation, that if we know the energy we should also know the momentum and velocity (to within a sign).

But there's another more careful way to calculate this, which gives a different answer. If you transform the position-space wavefunction into momentum space, you'll find that the momentum is not infinitely-sharply peaked at the expected values.  There's some probability of measuring a slightly-higher or slightly-smaller momentum (and velocity) from what you would expect from the energy argument.

A careful resolution of this is given in the paper, but the best way to understand it is that a high-accuracy momentum/velocity measurement is only possible if the uncertainty in the position gets very large.  But in a well, it *can't* get arbitrarily large; the particle is still somewhere in the well.  So there will always be some non-zero probability that the measured velocity isn't *exactly* one of the values which you are calculating here.

Comment: excellent exposition, thank you for this. -NN